# Vue.js - Open/close a dynamic Sidebar thought diferrent components (Navbar to Sidebar) using vuex

Tags: boolean, vue.js, components, vuex, state-management

I'm trying to make a dynamic Sidebar on my website, but the menu button is in another component (Navbar). How can I get them to communicate with each other through vuex? Look, I know how to do it in the same component, but I'm struggling here to pass this boolean state from Navbar to Sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your store as follows:
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        sideBarOpen: false
    },
    getters: {
        g_sideBarOpen(state){
            return state.sideBarOpen
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        toggleSideBar(state){
            state.sideBarOpen = !state.sideBarOpen;
        }
    },
});
```

In NavBar component click listener for menu button

```
<template>
  <button @click="toggleSideBar" class=myMenuBtn"></button>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        methods:{
            toggleSideBar(){
                this.$store.commit('toggleSideBar');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

now in the main component where you host the **SideBar** component

```
<template>
  <side-bar v-show="showSideBar"></side-bar>
</template>

<script>
    import SideBar from './SideBar'
    export default{
        components:{
            'side-bar': SideBar
        },
        computed:{
            showSideBar(){
                this.$store.getters.g_sideBarOpen;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) is to have a common state across your components. You don't have to communicate this from one component, they share the state.

If you commit a mutation in one component, to set a variable : `state.myVar`, you can access the modified `this.$store.state.myVar` in the other component, which will always reflect the modified value.

Please add your code samples if it is not working like this.